# How to Overplot Contour data on World Map in IDL?

Tags: image, matlab, plot, contour, idl-programming-language

I am trying to take data that is tied to latitude and longitude, and plot it over a world map in IDL. (The calculation code I have inherited is in IDL, and I must call it a bunch of times, which is why I want to figure out how to do it in there, instead of moving it off the server in huge netCDF files)

I am having issues with MAP and CONTOUR in idl, and would appreciate some help with the implementation of those two functions.

I have already tried using the MAP function, and using CONTOUR. I am having issues with MAP returning the error "Incorrect number of arguments" when I call it exactly the same as they do in this example: https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/CONTOUR.html

My code currently:

```
m = MAP('Geographic', xrange = [-180,180], yrange = [-90, 90], /CURRENT)

c = contour(data, lons, lats, levels = levels, OVERPLOT = m, GRID_UNITS = 'degrees')

mc = MAPCONTINENTS()
```

I would expect that this would produce a contour plot of the data over a world map. However, it won't even run the first function because it says there are not enough arguments. This doesn't make much sense though, because I am literally using more info than the example. Any suggestions?